# Простой цикл в bat файле, ввод с клавиатуры, сравнение. Некорректно работает программа

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Во программа

```
@echo off
cls
 for /l %%i in (0,1,2) do (
  set /p v="Enter Yes or No: "
  if "%v%"=="Yes" (
    echo RIGHT
  ) else (
    echo WRONG
 )
)
```

Собственно я с клавиатуры ввожу либо Yes либо No и в зависимости от того что я ввёл у меня выполняется условие, проблема в том что запустив первый раз программу у меня запоминается первое значение `v` и далее независимо что я введу у меня в переменной `v` будет сохраняться значение которое я вводил в последнем запуске программы в конце.
Приведу пример:
1-й запуск:

```
Enter Yes or No: No
WRONG
Enter Yes or No: Yes
WRONG
Enter Yes or No: Yes
WRONG
```

Я ввёл сначала No оно отработало правильно затем Yes и начиная с этого оно теперь не меняет значение в переменной `v`в конце я опять ввёл YES и опять получил результат WRONG 
**2-й запуск:**

```
Enter Yes or No: Yes
RIGHT
Enter Yes or No: No
RIGHT
Enter Yes or No: No
RIGHT
```

Тут она запомнила последнее значение прошлого запуска где я вводил YES и так далее... 
и так далее то есть он запоминает последнее значение из предыдущего запуска программы и везде его пихает
Я пробовал отлаживать и вне цикла у меня это работает великолепно **но суть в том что я обрабатываю файл и без цикла я не могу обойтись** вот пример как это примерно работает без цикла

```
@echo off
cls
set /p v="Enter Yes or No: "
if "%v%"=="Yes" (
    echo RIGHT
) else (
    echo WRONG
)
set /p v="Enter Yes or No: "
if "%v%"=="Yes" (
    echo RIGHT
) else (
    echo WRONG
)

set /p v="Enter Yes or No: "
if "%v%"=="Yes" (
    echo RIGHT
) else (
    echo WRONG
)
```

Тут у меня уже три раза проделывается всё тоже самое что и в цикле но теперь если я пишу Yes он выводит RIGHT затем я пишу No он выводит WRONG и третий раз пишу Yes он выводит RIGHT, в общем всё работает как и подразумевалось.
Вот программа которая должна работать с файлом я просто беру и обрабатываю текстовый документ и должен вводит либо да либо нет в зависимости от считанных данных

```
@echo off
cls
set files=C:
for /f "delims=,  eol=; skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i in (users.txt) do (
    echo User: %%i  
    set /p %choice%="Enter: "
    if "%choice%"=="Yes" (
        echo %choice%
        echo %%j
    ) else (
        echo %choice%
        echo ERRRAIRI
    )
)
```

Я уже не могу понять как сделать что бы это работало всё в цикле правильно как и задумывалось.

Comment: enabledelayedexpansion

Comment: Я попробовал сделать как вы советовали через enabledelayedexpansion но у меня всё равно не получается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls
 for /l %%i in (0,1,2) do (
  set /p v="Enter Yes or No: "
  if "!v!"=="Yes" (
    echo RIGHT
  ) else (
    echo WRONG
 )
)
```